# I cant have an image (html)

Tags: html

I'm coding html and putting in images but they wont load.

How can I fix this?

```
<img src="file:///D:/Minecraft.png">
```

```
<img src="file:///D:/Minecraft.png">
<img src="file:///D:/MinecraftDungeons.png"> 
<img src="file:///D:/MyFirendPedro.png">
<br>
<img src="file:///D:/Roblox.png">
<img src="file:///D:/Roblox_Vesteria.png">
<img src="file:///D:/Retro.jpg">
 <br>
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about the folder structure. We usually keep images close to the HTML files if not inside the same folder and referenced using relative paths, So as to export them as a whole while deploying.

Comment: want me to add a screenshot of the code but like include most of the code?

Comment: Screenshot of the folder structure would be helpful.

Comment: i added more text so you guys can help me!

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the error you are getting in the console. Is it a 404 ?

Comment: its not a 404 its just it will only show a weird small piece of paper im assuming its a defult picture or smth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your src path to src="D:/Minecraft.png"

Comment: it didnt work btw the way i got the image is by going ctrl+o and then getting it and copying the link is that ok?

Comment: Are you get "Not allowed to load local resource" error in your browser console?